# Pseudo-Boolean Function - Interpretation of a Property

Tags: terminology, integer-programming, discrete-optimization, operations-research, binary-programming

I am considering the following Pseudo-Boolean function $f:\{0,1\}^{3}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, where f is

$$ f(I_{1},I_{2},I_{3}) = \left(I_{1}+I_{2}+I_{3}\right)^{\beta} $$

with $\beta>0$.

after some manipulations I arrive to the following expression,

$$\left[\left(I_{1}+I_{2}+I_{3}\right)^{\beta}-\left(I_{1}+I_{2}\right)^{\beta}-\left(I_{1}+I_{3}\right)^{\beta}-\left(I_{2}+I_{3}\right)^{\beta}+I_{1}^{\beta}+I_{2}^{\beta}+I_{3}^{\beta}\right]>0$$

One can show that this inequality holds whenever $\beta<1$ or $\beta>2$. To me, this is reminiscent of the first derivative being convex in the scalar case.

Also, a sufficient condition for this inequality hold is that for any combination of $i,j,k$ the following holds

$$\left(I_{i}+I_{j}+I_{k}\right)^{\beta}-\left(I_{i}+I_{k}\right)^{\beta}-\left(I_{j}+I_{k}\right)^{\beta}+I_{k}^{\beta}>\left(I_{i}+I_{j}\right)^{\beta}-(I_{i}^{\beta}+I_{j}^{\beta})$$

that sort of says that the double difference is larger than the first difference of something like that.

Therefore, my question is whether this type of function has a precise characterization and/or it has a name and further properties that one can exploit. I do not know if this rings a bell to any of you, but any reference/intuition or precise characterization would be very helpful.

Comment: The fact that the inequality holds for $(1-\beta)(\beta-2)>0$ indicates that these holds both in cases in which $f$ is supermodular or submodular. I believe it has to do with the fact that when I move two coordinates at a time the change must be larger than when I move one at a time.

Comment: I see what you are asking in a general context : let $f : \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ be such that for every $x,y,z$ we have $f(x+y+z) - f(x+z) - f(y+z) + f(z)\geq f(x+y)-(f(x)+f(y))$. Then what can we say about $f$? Would this be right? Match it with your expression. Probably $f(0) = 0$ is also required, I think. Yes, submodularity very much comes to mind in this expression.

Comment: Thanks! Yes, indeed $f(0)=0$. What I do not understand is why does this hold for when $\beta>2$, which defines a submodular function.

If things were continuous, and not binary, I would interpret this as convexity of the first derivative. 

However, in this binary case, is there any other way to interpret this?

Comment: Hi maney, unsure in the binary case of the interpretation. More like I don't know what standard interpretations look like in pseudo-Boolean algebra!

Comment: Given the decomposition of a psuedo boolean function as a finite degree polynomial, maybe we can find conditions on the coefficients which satisfy the condition you provide?